# Detect which version of .Net is installed? (.Net 3.5 not running on .Net 4)

Tags: .net

Despite Mircrosoft's assurances later .Net will always be backward compatible ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb822049.aspx ) my .Net 3.5 SP1 app does not run a box with .Net4.....

The user is presented with an error that sheds no light on why the app will not run:

> "Unable to find a version of the runtime to run this application."

Great.

So I would like write another app altogether that will run and check if they can run the app, proabably in C++. How can I check what version of .Net is installed and if for sure my app .Net app will run otherwise point the user in the right direction to install the required .Net?

Comment: You're probably targeting the full framework on a machine with only the Client Framework installed.

Comment: Im targeting .Net 3.5... anyway clients could only have client framework installed so I still need to solve the problem..

Comment: @Fëanor: Are you targeting Client or Full?

Comment: Is this using MSCharts by any chance? I've just been fighting to get my app to work. Unforunately, you have to change what you link against when you get to v4.0..

Comment: There is no option to target Client of Full with 3.5! My problem is the same as this guys and solving it seems easy: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/477328/unable-to-find-a-version-of-the-runtime-to-run-this-application-for-applications-built-in-net-3-5-vs-2008, though I wonder if people wit out .Net 4 will now have a problem...

Comment: You don't have to write an app, VS can auto-generate it from a couple of mouse clicks.  It not only detects, it installs .NET.  Use a Setup project.

Comment: @Hans cool, though it seems I needn't even go that far: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/477328/unable-to-find-a-version-of-the-runtime-to-run-this-application-for-applications-built-in-net-3-5-vs-2008

Comment: Hmya, a config file doesn't get a framework installed. You still require .NET 4.0 on the machine. A Setup project can do that too.  Pick the one you have tested against and can support.

Comment: @Hans .Net 4 is on! Though I will use a setup project too for users who may not have .Net 3.5 SP1 or later.. thanks!

Answer (score 3):

[Check the registry](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315291).

Comment: That's what I've always done. Seems to work well. You can do the .net checks before the app loads too and warn the user if there's an issue.

Answer (score 1):

Your .Net 3.5 app should still be able to run, but you'll [have to add an entry to your application config file to opt your application into running on .NET Framework 4](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/477328/unable-to-find-a-version-of-the-runtime-to-run-this-application-for-applications-built-in-net-3-5-vs-2008):

```
<configuration>
<startup>
    <supportedRuntime version = "v4.0"/>
</startup>
</configuration>
```